# Python/PYQT5 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'slideLeftMenu'

Tags: python, pyqt5, attr

I do not understand why I receive this attribute error.

**"AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'slideLeftMenu'**"

slideLeftMenu is defined immediately after its called "self.slideLeftMenu" by pushButton8

my ui_Interface.py is not included but can be if its helpful

### main.py

```
############################
##IMPORTS
#############################
import sys
import os
from PySide2 import *
######################
##IMPORT GUI FILE
##########################
from ui_interface import *
##########################
#####################################
## MAIN WINDOW CLASS################

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.show
    ######################################################
    ## REMOVE WINDOWS TITLE BAR
    #######################################################
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    ######################################################
    ## MAIN BACKGROUND TRANSPARANCY
    #######################################################
    self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    ######################################################
    ## Shadow Effect Style
    #######################################################
    self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
    self.shadow.setBlurRadius(50)
    self.shadow.setXOffset(0)
    self.shadow.setYOffset(0)
    self.shadow.setColor(QColor(0, 92, 157, 550))
    ######################################################
    ## SET SHADOW TO CENTRAL WIDGET
    #######################################################
    self.ui.centralwidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
    ######################################################
    ## SET WindowsIcon & Title
    #####################################################
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(":/Icons/add.svg"))
    self.setWindowTitle("Dogma Indexer")
    #######################################################
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    ####################################################
    ####MINIMIZE GRIP
    ###################################################
    QSizeGrip(self.ui.Size_Grip)
    ############################
    ## Close Window
    ####################################################
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.
        close())

    ## Minimize Window
    ####################################################
    self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.
        showMinimized())
    self.show()


    ###################################################
    ## Restore/Maximize Window
    ###################################################
    self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.
        restore_or_maximize_window())

    ###################################################
    #Hidden Menu Toggle
    #################################################

    self.ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.slideLeftMenu())

    ####################################################################
    ######## Slide Function
    ####################################################################
    def slideLeftMenu(self):
        ### Get Menu Width
        width = self.ui.Side_menu_Container.Width()

        ### If Minimized
        if width == 0:
            # Expand Menu
            newWidth = 200
       #if maximized
        else:
        #Restore menu
            newWidth = 0


    ##############################

    ## Move window function
    ###################################################   \\\\\\\ FIX LATER
    #def moveWindow(e):
     #   if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
      #      self.move(self.pos() + e.globalPos() - self.clickPosition)
       #     self.clickPosition = e.globalPos()
      #        e.accept()
    #self.ui.header_frame.mouseMoveEvent = moveWindow

    #self.show()

#
## EXECUTE APP
##########################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
##########################################
```

Comment: Why is your `def __init__(self):` block not indented? You cannot do this. But then the code should not get executed at all. Anyway we cannot reproduce anything if we miss parts of your code. 
You do not even have the imports for PyQT. And my anaconda has no PySide2.

Comment: @GiovanniTardini I think this sometimes happens to the first line of code when copy-pasting to SO. You can install PySide2 if you want...

Comment: For future reference, you should provide a "minimal" example of the code, there's too much stuff here...

Comment: @AmmarT. There are many issues with your code: 1. The indentation of `slideLeftMenu` is wrong; 2. `width()` for the `Side_Menu_Container` must be lower case; 3. Those lambdas are useless, just use the function reference without the parentheses); 4. The definition of a function should not be before it's calling, even if it's used in a lambda; 5. Only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not functions, variables and attributes; 6. Avoid unnecessary commenting in the code: comments should clarify the code (which should be clear enough in the first place), non distract from it.

Answer (score 3):

Is the function defined under the `__init__` function? They should both be under the class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def my_func(self):
        pass
```

Also, you are calling the function (you put `()` after the function). try:

```
self.ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.slideLeftMenu)
```

Actually, when connecting signals you don't need to use lambda functions unless you need to pass arguments to the connected functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My function is defined in the same class under the __init__ function but was misplaced due to an indentation error. No errors when running the code, but clicking the button to start function doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: To make sure that the button is actually connected to the function you should run it in debug mode or put trivial code at the beginning of the function (`print('I'm here!')`)

Comment: @AmmarT. You don't understand. Your `slideLeftMenu` is at the **wrong indentation level**: it's defined *inside* the `__init__`, with 8 spaces from the beginning of the line,  but it should be at the *class* level, with just 4 spaces (exactly like `__init__`).

Comment: @SiP actally, there's nothing wrong in calling the function, as long as it's inside lambda (which was unnecessary in this case, as you correctly pointed out). It's also good practice to suggest running the code in a terminal or prompt, as IDEs can sometime fail to show errors (which is common for Qt) or the full traceback.

Comment: @musicamante maybe my language wasn’t clear, I meant you don’t “have” to use lambda if you don’t call the function